How to upload xlsx attachments from Gmail to Gdrive using Gmail Api and Gdrive Api V3
I know how to get attachments in google spreadsheet format using GmailApp, but this method is very slow and not suitable when there are a lot of files.
I am trying to get attachment files from mail using GmailApi V1 and GoogleDriveApi V3, but I am facing some problems:
configObject
// Объект конфигурации для управления параметрами поиска файлов Excel
const config = {
  folderId: '1cZeymn1OUhew0xc3uO_MeS4aDTH3gxXp', // ID папки на Google Drive для поиска файлов Excel
  query: 'is:unread has:attachment', // запрос для поиска непрочитанных сообщений с вложениями
  mimeTypes: {
    excel: [
      MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL, // стандартный MIME-тип для Excel файлов
      'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' // MIME-тип для современных Excel файлов (.xlsx)
    ],
    googleSheets: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS // MIME-тип для Google Таблиц
  }
};

1. Sample1
    const saveGmailAttachmentsToDrive = () => {

    // Включите Gmail API и Drive API в разделе Google Cloud Platform API Dashboard для вашего проекта
    const response = Gmail.Users.Messages.list('me', { q: 'is:unread has:attachment ' });

    // Проверяем наличие сообщений
     if (response && response.messages && response.messages.length > 0) {
      response.messages.forEach((messageWrapper) => {
      const messageId = messageWrapper.id;
      const message = Gmail.Users.Messages.get('me', messageId, { format: 'full' });

    // Проверяем наличие вложений
    if (message.payload && message.payload.parts) {
    message.payload.parts.forEach((part) => {
      // Ищем части с 'body.attachmentId' (что указывает на вложение)

      if (part.body && part.body.attachmentId) {
        const attachment = Gmail.Users.Messages.Attachments.get('me', messageId, part.body.attachmentId)
        const content = attachment.data.map(code => String.fromCharCode(code)).join('');
        console.log(content);

        // Создаем Blob из данных вложения
        const blob = Utilities.newBlob(content, part.mimeType, part.filename);

        const fileMetdata = {
          name: part.filename,
          parents: [config.folderId]
        };

        const response = Drive.Files.create(fileMetdata, blob);
        console.log(response);
      }
    });
    }
    });
    }

The current script retrieves attachments using the forEach method. The attachment data retrieved from the JSON response is as follows:
 [80,75,3,4,20,0,8,8,8,0,115,80,-107,88,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,24,0,0,0,120,108,47,100,114,97,119,105,110,103,115,47,100,114,97,119,105,110,103,49,46,120,109,108,-99,-48,93,110,-62,48,12,7,-16,19,-20,14,85,-34,105,90,24,19,67,20,94,-48,78,48,14,-32,37,110,27,-111,-113,-54,14,-93,-36,126,-47,74,54,105,123,1,30,109,-53,63,-7,-17,-51,110,116,-74,-8,68,98,19,124,35,-22,-78,18,]

Although when I get attachment data using API Explorer I get data in base64 format
Then I only managed to save the file in xlsx format, but when I open it I get an error, I try to convert it to google spreadsheet and I also get an error this file format cannot be converted to google spreadsheet.
2. Sample2
This code works fine, but it will take a lot of time if there are a lot of attachments and emails.
/**
 * Обработка вложений из Gmail и конвертация Excel файлов в Google Sheets.
 * @return {object[]} Массив объектов с ID сконвертированных таблиц.
 */
const convertToGoogleSpreadsheet = () => {
  // Получаем список всех непрочитанных сообщений с вложениями в Gmail
  const threads = GmailApp.search(config.query);
  const messages = threads.flatMap(thread => GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads([thread]));
  const convertedSheetIds = []; // Инициализируем массив для хранения ID конвертированных таблиц

  // Перебираем каждое сообщение для обработки вложений
  messages.flat().forEach(message => {
    const attachments = message.getAttachments();
    // Перебираем вложения в каждом сообщении
    attachments.forEach(attachment => {
      // Проверяем MIME-тип вложения, чтобы убедиться, что он соответствует формату Excel
      if (config.mimeTypes.excel.includes(attachment.getContentType())) {
        try {
          // Создание объекта для дальнейшей вставки файла на Google Drive
          const resource = {
            name: attachment.getName(),
            mimeType: config.mimeTypes.googleSheets,
            parents: [config.folderId],
          };

          // Конвертируем вложение в Google Sheets с помощью API Google Drive
          const blob = attachment.getAs(config.mimeTypes.excel[0]);
          const file = Drive.Files.create(resource, blob, { convert: true });

          // Логируем информацию о сохраненном файле
          console.log(`Файл ${attachment.getName()} сохранен с ID: ${file.id}`);
          // Добавляем ID сконвертированной таблицы в массив
          convertedSheetIds.push({ id: file.id });
        } catch (error) {
          // Логирование ошибок при конвертации и сохранении файла
          logError('convertToGoogleSpreadsheet', error);
        }
      }
    });
  });
}


What exactly is the issue with your current solution?   if its just speed you may have better luck on Code review

@Linda Lawton I have a problem with sample1., because this script does not properly convert the data into xlsx format so that it can be opened.

In the first example your not adding a mimetype to the fileMetdata .  In the second one your adding a google sheets mimetype its not going to upload it as xlsx its going to import it as a google sheet.   What do you expect it to do?

@Linda Lawton I need the sample1 script to create a google table, but the problem is that it converts data from attachment using fromCharCode badly, with such decoding the xlsx table just won't open, that's the problem.

google drive api can only upload files it has no control over how its formatted that's up to you.

I found the following solution for myself:

I used asynchronous execution of functions.
I used UrlFetchApp.fetchAll method and multipart download.

Here is my current code which works very fast and reliable:
/**
 * Извлекает адрес электронной почты отправителя из сообщения.
 * @param {string} messageId - Идентификатор сообщения Gmail.
 * @return {string|null} Адрес электронной почты отправителя или null, если он не найден.
 */
const getSenderEmail = (message) => {
  // Извлечение заголовка 'From' (отправитель письма)
  const headers = message.payload.headers;
  const fromHeader = headers.find(header => header.name.toLowerCase() === 'from');

  // Если заголовок 'From' найден, возвращаем его значение, иначе - null
  return fromHeader ? fromHeader.value.replace(/["<>]/g, '') : null;
}

/**
 * Выполняет операцию обработки всех тредов с непрочитанными сообщениями, содержащими вложения
 * соответствующего MIME типа, и возвращает информацию для пакетной загрузки.
 *
 * @return {Object} Объект с информацией о вложениях для пакетной загрузки.
 */
const processUnreadMessagesWithAttachments = async (scriptProperties) => {
  let attachmentsInfo = [];
  try {
    const threadsResponse = await Gmail.Users.Threads.list('me', { q: config.query });
    const threads = threadsResponse.threads || [];

    if (threads) {
      const threadIds = threads.map(thread => thread.id);

      // Сохраняем идентификаторы тредов в свойствах скрипта
      scriptProperties.setProperties({ 'unreadThreadIds': JSON.stringify(threadIds) });


      for (const thread of threads) {
        const threadAttachments = await processThreadAttachments(thread.id);
        attachmentsInfo = attachmentsInfo.concat(threadAttachments);
      }
    }
    return attachmentsInfo;
  } catch (error) {
    logError('processUnreadMessagesWithAttachments', error);
  }
};

/**
 * Обрабатывает вложения в заданном треде электронной почты и возвращает массив объектов с идентификаторами вложений и метаданными.
 *
 * @param {string} threadId - ID треда, вложения которого необходимо обработать.
 * @return {Array<Object>} Массив объектов для каждого вложения с его ID и метаданными.
 */
const processThreadAttachments = async (threadId) => {
  try {
    const threadData = Gmail.Users.Threads.get('me', threadId);
    return threadData.messages.flatMap(message => {
      return (message.payload.parts || []).flatMap(part => {
        if (part.body.attachmentId && config.mimeTypes.excel.includes(part.mimeType)) {
          return {
            attachmentId: part.body.attachmentId,
            filename: part.filename,
            mimeType: part.mimeType,
            messageId: message.id,
            threadId: threadId,
            sender: getSenderEmail(message) // получаем отправителей 
          }
        }
        return [];
      }).filter(Boolean) // Убираем undefined значения
    });
  } catch (error) {
    logError('processThreadAttachments', error);
  }
};

/**
 * Инициирует процесс пакетной загрузки файлов.
 * Эта функция является входной точкой для начала загрузки файлов на Google Drive на основе вложений 
 * в непрочитанных сообщениях Gmail, соответствующих определенным MIME-типам.
 */
const startBatchUpload = async () => {
  // Получаем объект для работы со свойствами скрипта, где будем хранить данные между выполнениями.
  const scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();

  // Получаем OAuth 2.0 токен для текущего пользователя, что позволит делать авторизованные запросы к Google API.
  const accessToken = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();

  // Получаем список вложений, которые нужно загрузить. Эта функция предполагается быть реализованной 
  // и должна обрабатывать все непрочитанные сообщения в Gmail, извлекая нужные вложения.
  const attachmentsInfo = await processUnreadMessagesWithAttachments(scriptProperties);

  if (attachmentsInfo.length == 0) {
    console.log(`Нет новых закзаов`);
    retutn;
  }
  // Сохраняем необходимую информацию для процесса загрузки в свойства скрипта.
  // Это позволяет удерживать состояние между выполнениями функции, особенно полезно при использовании триггеров.
  scriptProperties.setProperties({
    'attachmentsInfo': JSON.stringify(attachmentsInfo), // информация о вложениях, представленная в виде строки JSON
    'accessToken': accessToken, // сохраняемый токен доступа
    'currentIndex': '0' // начальный индекс текущего вложения, с которого начнется загрузка
  });

  // Запускаем процесс пакетной загрузки файлов, вызывая функцию, которая обрабатывает загрузку.
  triggerBatchUpload();
};

/**
 * Триггер вызывает пакетную загрузку файлов на Google Drive.
 * Запускает обработку следующего пакета файлов или завершает процесс, если все файлы обработаны.
 */
const triggerBatchUpload = async () => {
  // Получаем доступ к сохраненным свойствам скрипта
  const scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  const attachmentsInfo = JSON.parse(scriptProperties.getProperty('attachmentsInfo'));
  const accessToken = scriptProperties.getProperty('accessToken');
  let currentIndex = parseInt(scriptProperties.getProperty('currentIndex'), 10);

  // Проверяем, не была ли обработка уже завершена
  if (currentIndex >= attachmentsInfo.length) {
    deleteAllPropertiesExceptUnreadThreadIds(scriptProperties); // Удаляем все сохраненные свойства
    deleteAllTriggers(); // Удаляем все триггеры, так как загрузка завершена
    addTrigger('doOrders', 1 * 20 * 1000) // запускаем процесс оработки заказов
    console.log('Все файлы были обработаны.');
    return;
  }

  // формируем массив отправителей
  const senderData = attachmentsInfo.slice(currentIndex, currentIndex + 3).map(info => ({ sender: info.sender }));
  // Формируем массив запросов на получение данных вложений из Gmail
  const batchInfo = attachmentsInfo.slice(currentIndex, currentIndex + 3);
  const requests = batchInfo.map(info => ({
    url: `https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/${info.messageId}/attachments/${info.attachmentId}`,
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
      Accept: 'application/json'
    },
    filename: info.filename,
    mimeType: info.mimeType,
    muteHttpExceptions: true
  }));

  // Подготовим массивы для хранения blob данных и метаданных файлов
  let blobs = [];
  let attachmentsData = [];

  // Выполнение запросов и обработка полученных данных вложений
  if (requests.length > 0) {
    const responses = await UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(requests);
    responses.forEach((response, index) => {
      if (response.getResponseCode() === 200) {
        // Если ответ успешный, обрабатываем данные вложения
        const request = requests[index];
        const attachmentData = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
        const blob = Utilities.base64DecodeWebSafe(attachmentData.data);
        blobs.push(blob);
        attachmentsData.push({
          name: request.filename,
          mimeType: 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet',
          parents: [config.folderId]
        });
      } else {
        console.error(`Ошибка получения данных вложения: ${response.getResponseCode()}`);
      }
    });
  }

  // Запустим асинхронную функцию загрузки файлов на Google Drive
  batchUploadFiles({ attachmentsData, blobs, senderData });

  // Обновляем индекс текущего выполнения и сохраняем его в свойствах скрипта
  currentIndex += batchInfo.length;
  scriptProperties.setProperty('currentIndex', currentIndex.toString());

  // Если не все файлы обработаны, установим новый триггер для продолжения загрузки
  if (currentIndex < attachmentsInfo.length) {
    addTrigger('triggerBatchUpload', 1 * 60 * 1000); // Запустить следующий шаг через 30 секунд
  } else {
    deleteAllPropertiesExceptUnreadThreadIds(scriptProperties); // Процесс загрузки завершён, удаляем свойства
    deleteAllTriggers(); // Удаляем все триггеры
    addTrigger('doOrders', 1 * 20 * 1000) // запускаем процесс оработки заказов
    console.log('Все файлы были обработаны.');
  }
};

/**
 * Функция, которая будет вызвана триггером и отметит ранее сохраненные треды, как прочитанные.
 */
const markThreadsAsRead = () => {
  try {
    const scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
    const threadIdsString = scriptProperties.getProperty('unreadThreadIds');
    if (!threadIdsString) {
      return;
    }
    const threadIds = JSON.parse(threadIdsString);

    threadIds.forEach(threadId => {
      // Отмечаем каждое сообщение из треда, как прочитанное
      Gmail.Users.Threads.modify({ removeLabelIds: ['UNREAD'] }, 'me', threadId);
    });

    // Удаляем идентификаторы тредов из свойств скрипта после их обработки
    scriptProperties.deleteProperty('unreadThreadIds');

    console.log('Unread threads are marked as read.');
  } catch (error) {
    logError('markThreadsAsRead', error);
  }
};

/**
 * Удаляет все свойства скрипта, кроме 'unreadThreadIds'.
 */
const deleteAllPropertiesExceptUnreadThreadIds = (scriptProperties) => {
  const properties = scriptProperties.getProperties();

  // Получаем массив ключей свойств и удаляем каждое свойство, не являющееся 'unreadThreadIds'
  Object.keys(properties).forEach(key => {
    if (key !== 'unreadThreadIds') {
      scriptProperties.deleteProperty(key);
    }
  });

  // Логирование успешного выполнения операции
  console.log('Все свойства, кроме "unreadThreadIds", были успешно удалены.');
};

/**
 * Выполняет пакетную загрузку файлов на Google Drive.
 */
async function batchUploadFiles(data) {
  try {
    // Получение доступного OAuth 2.0 токена для текущей сессии пользователя
    const accessToken = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
    // Получаем информацию о вложениях и созданные blob'ы
    const { attachmentsData, blobs, senderData } = data;
    const boundary = "xxxxxxxxxx"; // Уникальная граница нужна для разделения частей в multipart запросе

    // Создаем массив запросов для каждого вложения
    const requests = attachmentsData.map((metadata, index) => {
      // Использование шаблонных литералов для формирования multipart тела запроса
      let data = `--${boundary}\r\n`;
      data += `Content-Disposition: form-data; name="metadata"\r\n`;
      data += `Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8\r\n\r\n`;
      data += `${JSON.stringify(metadata)}\r\n`; // Добавление метаданных файла

      data += `--${boundary}\r\n`;
      data += `Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="${metadata.name}"\r\n`;
      data += `Content-Type: ${config.mimeTypes.excel[0]}\r\n\r\n`;

      // TODO: Этот блок кода предполагает наличие массива байт в blobs, который нужно будет преобразовать в blob
      let payload = [...Utilities.newBlob(data).getBytes(), ...blobs[index]];
      payload = [...payload, ...Utilities.newBlob(`\r\n--${boundary}--`).getBytes()]; // Закрытие multipart тела

      // Формируем объект запроса для fetchAll
      return {
        url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
          'Content-Type': `multipart/related; boundary=${boundary}`
        },
        payload: payload,
        muteHttpExceptions: true
      };
    });

    // Выполняем пакетные запросы для загрузки файлов
    const responses = await UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(requests);

    // Обработка ответов и логирование результатов
    const log = responses.map((response, index) => {
      if (response.getResponseCode() === 200) {
        return {
          'Файл': JSON.parse(response.getContentText()).name,
          'Отправитель': senderData[index].sender,
          'Статус': 'успешно загружен'
        }
      } else {
        return {
          'Ошибка загрузки файла': response.getContentText(),
          'Отправитель': senderData[index].sender,
          'Статус': 'неудачно'
        }
      }
    });
    console.log(JSON.stringify(log, null, 2));
    // отправляем сообщения в телеграм
    sendMessage(JSON.stringify(log, null, 2));
  } catch (error) {
    // Логирование и передача информации об ошибке
    logError('batchUploadFiles', error)
  }
}

